# Create a Custom navigation bar with two "bars". (View the image)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

[image: Navigation Bar]

How do I create a navigation bar like this and make the black rectangle under `Near Me` move when I slide to the left/right.

I am using a `pageviewcontroller` to enable the slide function but I have no idea on how to make a navigation bar like that, any tip would be helpful.

Swift language preferred.

Comment: Is the "Friends / Near Me" indicator _in_ the nav bar or _below_ the nav bar?

Comment: Right, the "Friends / Near Me" doesn't actually have to be in the nav bar. Does the structure of your app always have a nav bar that is the height of both those elements?

Comment: "Friends/Near Me" bar can be a custom made i suppose, the nav bar is not in the structure. I made the nav bar in Sketch. Should i create two nav bars and then add "Friends / Near Me" as buttons?. The black rectangle is something that i tought was a nice feature but if it is impossible then i will leave it out. @matt

Comment: The hard part is setting up a bar other than the nav bar that stays. It would be a lot easier if this were a tab bar controller interface where Friends and Near Me were the tabs. Then the whole thing would just fall into your lap.

Comment: Do you think i should use a nav controller and use the "inferred" top bar for it, then add a custom nav bar and change colour. Then add button as Friends and Near Me? @matt